# Crop string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert one column for two, and send to first a numeric symbol,
(1,2,3...) from parent column and char to second. Using only query in SQL Server

```
+-------+
| place |
+-------+
| 1a    |
| 2a    |
| 4c    |
| 4b    |
| 2d    |
| 2c    |
| 1d    |
| 1a    |
| 1b    |
| 3c    |
+-------+
```

Desired Output

```
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|    2 | a    |
|    3 | b    |
| ...  | ...  |
+------+------+
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please familiarize with the [posting rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This website is for helping you debug issues, however your question seems to be more along the lines of *"Someone write my code for me"*. Additionally, your question should be solvable *without relying on any external resources* (like imgur). You can edit your question to resolve these issues, otherwise you run the risk of having it closed.

Comment: Have a look at [`LEFT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql) and [`RIGHT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql). If you struggle, edit your post with **what you have tried**.

Answer (score 0):

If the numeric part is always the first one, then by using [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql) you can get the index of the last digit and afterwards just use [LEFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql) and [RIGHT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql) (as suggested by @Larnu)

```
declare @tbl as table (
    place varchar(5)
)

insert into @tbl values ('1a'), ('2b'), ('4c'), ('5e'), ('27gg')

select
    LEFT(place, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', place)) as col1
    ,RIGHT(place, LEN(place) - PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', place)) as col2
from @tbl
```